# Accessibility (VO) does not scroll past after certain row

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiaccessibility

I've implemented a collectionView in a tableView cell in one my (Swift) projects where each `UITableViewCell` contains a `UICollectionView` and each collectionView then has `UICollectionViewCell`'s. And my collectionView cell is again customized in a Xib.

Now when I tried to implement accessibility on this, this is going through some weird behavior.
What I did so far -

> (1) Since each `UITableViewCell` contains `UICollectionView`, so I set tableView cell's accessibility to false.
>
> e.g. 
>   `dummyTableViewCell.isAccessibilityElement = false`
>
> (2) Then I override `UIAccessibilityContainer` methods on my UICollectionView class. 
>   e.g. 
>   `override func accessibilityElementCount() -> Int 
>   { return subViews.count }`
>
> and so on...

While this reads through each element of collectionView inside tableView cell, but then VO stops after 4th or 5th row and does not scroll past any more. I did try again with implementing `UIScrollView` delegate methods, but nothing is working out so far.

Comment: you are saying that you cant scroll the collection view in accessibility mode ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri collection view scroll is working fine when VO is on. It's the table view cell which is not scrolling after certain row. one of the reasons I could think of, it's not reading the table view cells which are yet to created but its reading fine those are already in the screen.

Comment: Did you try to scroll it manually with fingers ?